# Specifying amount of bytes to move over to string in C#

Tags: c#, append, byte

This is what I am trying to do. I am taking byte data from an incoming socket program. By default, the bytes passed in to be Encoded and appended to my string will be 1500 bytes since this is the size I defined for the bytes array. My question is, I would like to know how to pass in part of the byte array instead of the whole 1500 bytes.

```
IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(args[0]);
        System.Console.WriteLine("The local IP is {0}", localAddr);
        Int32 port = int.Parse(args[1]);
        System.Console.WriteLine("The port is {0}", port);
        TcpListener myListener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1500];
        string sem = "";
        do
        {
            int flag = 0;
            int rec = 1;
            Console.Write("Waiting");
            myListener.Start();
            Socket mySocket = myListener.AcceptSocket();
            // receiving the hl7 message  
            StringBuilder sbb = new StringBuilder();
            do{
            //    bytes = null;
           rec =  mySocket.Receive(bytes,SocketFlags.None);
      //     rec = mySocket.Receive(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("rec = {0} ",rec);
            for (int i=0; i<bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bytes[i]==0x1C)
                {
                flag = 1;
                }
            }
           sbb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));

            }while (flag == 0);
```

Comment: What language ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: I am guessing sbb is a StringBuilder, not a String, right?  And your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense anyway- why do you want to append an empty byte array to a string builder?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? The question is unclear

Comment: Sorry again, I am workng with another programmer and that was just a snippet of a bigger code block. I have updated the question with a larger segment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, let's be clear about what the code shown does:

- it creates an empty byte array
- it *decodes* from this array using an encoding, creating a new string
- it passes this string to append to a StringBuilder

What it doesn't do is "copy bytes to a string" - not least a string is essentially "char" data (16 bits each), not byte data. If you wanted to treat byte data as char data, it would just-about work for UTF-16 (depending on the endianness), but not ASCII.

Re choosing how much to append:

- Encoding.GetString has an overload to specify the offset and count of byte data to consider
- StringBuilder.Append has an overload to specify the offset and count of char data to consider

Either or both may be useful here; however, I don't think the code does what you think it does; there are easier ways to initialise a StringBuilder

Comment: Thanks for the replies...I realize now that I shold have included a larger amount of code structure. I am relatively new to the coding game.

Comment: @Greg in that instance, you want `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, rec)` - make sense? Oh, you should also ensure `rec` is `> 0` - if it is `<= 0` that means the incoming stream was closed - in which case no more data will be coming. You don't want to get stuck in an infinite loop. Also: you should only check `rec` of the buffer: `for (int i=0; i<rec; i++)` - no point checking any of it that didn't get data.

Comment: Marc that looks like excatly what I need. I will also use the suggestion of limiting the buffer check. Thanks so much for the help. Love this site ;)